# Counter Strike: Global Offensive Lags

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm playing CS:GO for a while now and on some days I'm really bad.

It was noticeable that on these days even my teammates from the same city I live in were lagging and "flying" from one point to another without a fluent movement.
My Ping is about 15ms and I've got an average of 250FPS (according to the steam fps viewer overlay).

Do you have any idea if it depends on my CS:GO settings, G Data Internet Security or something else?
The game runs on a SSD with an Intel i5, a Radeon HD7870 and I've got a stable 50K down and 10K up internet connection.

Thank you!

Johannes

Comment: 15ms ping with 250FPS sounds like you're fine.  Unless you're stuttering, it's not you.

Comment: But they've got the same ping as me, better computers and don't have these lags with other players

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like you have heavy packet loss somewhere between your home NAT router and the server you are playing on.

As a first step, you could enter `net_status` in the CS:GO console. This will give an output like the following:

```
] net_status
Net status for host 192.168.2.23:
- Config: Multiplayer, listen, 1 connections
- Ports: cl0 27005, sv1 27015, htv2 27020, htv13 0, 4 total.
- Latency: avg out 0.04s, in 0.01s
- Loss:    avg out 0.0, in 0.0     <====================== This line show packet loss
- Packets: net total out  65.0/s, in 64.5/s
           per client out 65.0/s, in 64.5/s
- Data:    net total out  8.9, in 10.3 kB/s
           per client out 8.9, in 10.3 kB/s
```

This shows the packet loss of incoming and outgoing packets (I don't know the units, maybe percent). If it says anything other than `0.0`, that's a reason to be suspicious. Something on the route between you and the server throws away packets. You should probably contact your internet service provider about the problem, unless you are willing to investigate further.

---

If you want to investigate furhter, you'll need the server's IP address. Enter `status` in the CS:GO-console and look for the line `udp/ip`:

```
] status
hostname:  xxxxxxx
version : 1.35.0.9/13509 6171 secure  
udp/ip  : 10.11.12.13:27015          <============== The part before the : is the IP
os      :  Linux
type    :  community dedicated
map     : de_dust2
players : 1 humans, 3 bots (12/0 max) (not hibernating)
```

Once you got that, you can test packet loss using the `ping` command<sup>1</sup>. This will tell you if the problem just exists inside CS:GO or if it really is a network problem. Just open a terminal (enter "cmd" in the start menu and press Enter) and enter the following (with the correct IP, obviously):

```
ping -t ip.of.the.server
```

Your PC then sends requests to that server and measure the time until it answers. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> will show you statistics like this:

```
Ping statistics for ip.of.the.server
    Packets: Sent = 467, Received = 467, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 20ms, Maximum = 23ms, Average = 21ms
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will terminate the ping program and show the same statistics.

If it says anything but `0% loss`, you've got a problem.

---

If you know something about how network protocols work and/or are willing to invest some time learning, you can try to find the cause of the issue yourself. [Here's a good tutorial about debugging packet loss](https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Tools_and_Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting_packet_loss_between_devices), which you can use as a starting point. ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151103151409/https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Tools_and_Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting_packet_loss_between_devices))

---

<sup>1. Disclaimer: Obviously this only measures loss of ICMP packets, not UDP or TCP, but normally these should correlate.</sup>

Comment: This is a good answer, though I'd include an explanation on how to fix the packet loss, if it can be rectified/helped.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ You're right, of course, but debugging packet loss is really hard, if not impossible, for the average home user, because it requires some expert knowledge on internet protocols. That's why I suggested contacting the ISP.

Comment: In case you are interested: You would need to find the route the packets are taking using `tracert` (which might or might not work due to the configuration of remote routers which you don't control), find out which of those routers drops packets (again, this might fail due to router config), and contact the operator of said router (I wouldn't even know how to find that out). Here's a writeup of the general process, though not a tutorial: http://serverfault.com/questions/207375/how-do-you-diagnose-packet-loss

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I think it's better now. :)

Comment: I tried "ping -n 100 google.com" and I lost 2 packages (directly after boot of my PC, maybe firewall was initialised?) the first time, 0 packages the second and again 2 the third time... I also used tracert and no * were visible so I think my connection is very stable.

I don't know how to get the IP adress of the CS:GO MM-servers but maybe I can use net_graph to see package loss..

Is it possible that these settings influence my performance:  _rate cl_cmdrate cl_updaterate cl_interp_ratio cl_interp fps_max_?

Comment: @Johannes when you join a server I think it shows you the IP in console, it'll say something like `connecting to 123.123.123.123`

Comment: Ok I will try tomorrow. I added an two way exception for CS:GO in my G Data Firewall and despite a higher ping (different server i guess) it worked pretty fine. Maybe it depends on the server (infrastructure) or there is one hop that results in an error more often

Comment: @Johannes Your PC should *never* lose packages, even when you just booted it. To find out the IP, try entering `status` in the CS:GO-Console when connected to a server. Then use that IP in the `ping` and `tracert` commands. Alternatively you can also type `net_status` in the CS:GO-console, which will tell you (among other things) the packet loss for the current game session.

Comment: @Fritz I tried that with net_graph 1 and it says Loss: 0%.. My Router (fritz.box) says that the connection is stable for more than 8 days and there are only 17 erros occured since this day. I have to try ping and tracert with the server adress soon

Comment: @Johannes Did you try that while you had those lag problems, or just now? Because you said, it's only some days. Another possibility would be that some packets are not lost, but severely delayed (by about a second, as you describe "flying"). However, I can't really imagine how that might happen, short of routing every 10th packet through China or something (Note: I consider this *highly* unlikely). And if that were the case, it would probably be easier to just switch to another ISP than trying to figure out what the problem is. :(

Comment: @Fritz I tried it just yesterday but there weren't any problems. I moved to another city two month ago and with my old provider (vodafone germany) it was even worse. I had this problem there nearly every day despite a ping of about 45ms. Now I live in a bigger city with 1&1 as my ISP (uses Deutsche Telekom infrastructure) and my Ping is better and the problem occurs not that often but it's still there. I will try a ping with my notebook too this afternoon and if there is package loss too, it has something todo with my ISP, if not, with my PC for gaming I guess...

Comment: @Johannes That approach sounds good. Did you use `ping -t`? Leave that to run for a while and press Ctrl+Break (Pause on a German keyboard) to get better statistics with more packets instead of just 4.

Comment: @Fritz I used `ping -n 20 domain.com` which does nearly the same but only 100 times. I'm right?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, that's good too, but it sends only 20 packets before stopping. You likely want to send more than 100 packets to get a meaningful packet loss percentage value. So either something like `ping -n 200` or `ping -t`.

Comment: @Fritz Sorry, this was an example, I tried n = 150 yesterday. I also pinged heise.de with this method and there was no package loss at all. Only with google.com I loose always 2 packages

Comment: I called 1&1 and they said that maybe something is wrong in the telephone switch (hosted by Deutsche Telekom). But I figured out that this package loss only occurs in the internet "prime time" between ~ 5PM and 11PM. I also tried some pings with my notebook too and it showed the same package loss.
I think I have to wait..